# Need a logical help to attain the below scenario

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

**Need to return the rows with the commented lines in the below code "Should return as a problem".**

This could have be done quickly using the fourth column, but imagine that i do not have the fourth column.

How to return the columns marked as 'Should return as a problem'

```
';with temp as (
select 'A' col1,'B' col2,'C' col3, 'Problem' col4--Should return as a problem
union ALL
select null, null, null,'Problem' --Should return as a problem
union ALL
select null, 'B', 'C','Problem' --Should return as a problem
union ALL
select 'A','B',null,'Problem' --Should return as a problem
union ALL
select 'A',null,'C','Problem' --Should return as a problem
union ALL
select 'A',null,null,'Not a Problem' --Should NOT return as a problem
union ALL
select null, 'B', null,'Not a Problem' --Should NOT return as a problem
union ALL
select null,null,'C','Not a Problem' --Should NOT return as a problem
)
select * from temp WHERE  COALESCE( col1, col2, col3) IS NOT NULL 
                     or COALESCE( col1, col2, col3) IS NULL'
```

Comment: Confused why you have an OR condition in your WHERE clause. This will return everything. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Could you delete first and last quote in your code? I makes it difficult to read

Comment: Can you clarify on Problem not problem category and why you are marking like that

Comment: what is logic of 'COALESCE( col1, col2, col3) IS NOT NULL or COALESCE( col1, col2, col3) IS NULL'  what you want return with this where clause with no fourth column.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want to return rows that have at least two `NULL` values.  Here is one way:

```
where ((case when col1 is null then 1 else 0 end) +
       (case when col2 is null then 1 else 0 end) +
       (case when col3 is null then 1 else 0 end)
      ) = 2
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick solution

Answer (score 0):

```
select *from temp where
(col1 is not null and (col2 is  null and col3 is  null)) or
(col2 is not null and (col1 is  null and col3 is  null)) or
(col3 is not null and (col1 is  null and col2 is  null))
```